# How can I GROUP BY "identical" strings of different lengths?

Tags: python, mysql, group-by

I have a database of hymn instances as they appear in various hymnbooks.
The table is set up roughly like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Hymns` (
  `HymnID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HymnbookID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HyNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HyName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `HyFirstLine` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `HyFirstLineDif` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SongID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TextID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TuneID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`HymnID`),
  KEY `HymnbookID` (`HymnbookID`),
  KEY `SongID` (`SongID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=134381 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `Hymns` (`HymnID`, `HymnbookID`, `HyNumber`, `HyName`,
  `HyFirstLine`, `HyFirstLineDif`, `SongID`, `TextID`, `TuneID`)
VALUES (642, 1, 26, 'Joseph Smith’s First Prayer',
  'Oh, how lovely was the morning', 1, 26, 26, 26);
```

Sometimes the first lines are the same, but cutting off at a different place – and sometimes they are different (the letters A and B aren't in the database, I just put them in to show same and different):

> Oh, how lovely was the morning [A]
>
> Oh, how lovely [A]
>
> Oh, how lovely was the morning! Radiant beamed [A]
>
> O how lovely was the morning! [B]

Is it possible to return only the longest version of the unique first lines, like this?:

> Oh, how lovely was the morning! Radiant beamed [A]
>
> O how lovely was the morning! [B]

Here's the query I have so far:

```
SELECT HyFirstLine
FROM Hymns
WHERE TextID = 26 AND HyFirstLine IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY HyFirstLine
```

EDIT: The data is being returned to Python as a list of dictionaries. Based on the comments, maybe it's better to filter after the fact with Python? I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. Adding the Python tag.

Comment: need program to loop it eg php

Comment: My suspicion is that you will either need a user-defined function to handle this, or possibly need to use a language like Java.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the dataset with `Cursor` or a `TempTable` maybe?

Comment: I'm using Python on my site, and the data is being returned to Python as a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Then why don't you just manipulate the list of dictionary within python? Thus removing the load from your database endpoint. Though this would scale depending on how big your data is.

Comment: If that's the simplest way, I'm open to that.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This is for MSSQL, not mySQL. My apologies. Hope the reference below could help you though.

Not tested but you'd probably need a stored procedure with something like this:

```
DECLARE @HyFirstLine varchar(255);
DECLARE @StoredHyFirstLine varchar(255);

DECLARE @OutputTable Table(HyFirstLine varchar(255))

DECLARE hy_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT HyFirstLine FROM Hymns;

OPEN hy_cursor;  

FETCH NEXT FROM hy_cursor  
INTO @HyFirstLine;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @OutputTable WHERE HyFirstLine like @HyFirstLine+'%')
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @OutputTable(HyFirstLine) VALUES(@HyFirstLine)
     END
   ELSE
     BEGIN
       SET @StoredHyFirstLine = (SELECT HyFirstLine FROM @OutputTable WHERE HyFirstLine like @HyFirstLine+'%')

       IF LEN(@HyFirstLine) > LEN(@StoredHyFirstLine)
         BEGIN
           UPDATE @OutputTable SET HyFirstLine = @HyFirstLine WHERE HyFirstLine like @HyFirstLine+'%'
         END
     END

   FETCH NEXT FROM hy_cursor  
   INTO @HyFirstLine;  
END  

CLOSE hy_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE hy_cursor;  

SELECT * FROM  @OutputTable
```